# Reflection POCO class and auto CreateInstance via .net6

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-6.0

The front-end only needs to pass in the entity name to achieve database queries,there is my code:

```
var entityType = Assembly.Load("system.domain").GetTypes().Where(a => a.Name == "AccountType").FirstOrDefault();
var repositoryType = typeof(infra.IRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
//????: CS0118 error,how to fix the error.
var r = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<infrastructure.IRepository<????>>();
```

thanks!

Comment: Why though? Sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: Do you have any good solutions @Fildor

Comment: Well, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to dynamically generate a repository via  class name,For example, by passing in a parameter "Person" and reflecting it，I can get  Infrastructure. IRepository<Person>repository, and  call  the method repository. getById()，Before that, I had already registered this object: services.AddScoped<IRepository<Person>,Repository<Person>);@Fildor

Comment: What's the point in making it this "dynamic"? Are you expecting changes to your model on a minute basis? Also: if you happen to be using Entity Framework (Core), you already have this for free at compiletime. Doing any of this via runtime reflection will become your bottleneck (not to mention the maintainance hell).